# get a notification from notificationCenter after returning from a phone call

Tags: ios, swift, phone-call, notificationcenter

I want to do an action after the user tapped on the call button and made a call then returned to the app.

This is my function for making a phone call :

```
let phoneURL = URL(string: String(format: "tel://%@", phoneNumber.englishNumbers))
UIApplication.shared.open(phoneURL!)
```

and I have set an observer on `CallView` in `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector (showFeedBack), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

After I made the call and pressed on the End button (the red button which ends the call). the `CallView` would appear but the notification won't get called.

Am I using the right notification? or is this the correct approach for detecting when a user made a phone call through your app and came back?

P.S. I have used `willResignActiveNotification` notification. but it send the notification before even making the call (when the alert is appeared and the user has not select anything yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CXCallObserver` to listen the call events as below,

```
import CallKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CXCallObserverDelegate {

    let co = CXCallObserver()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        co.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }

    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
        if call.hasEnded {
            print("Call is ended")
        }
        if call.hasEnded == false && call.hasConnected {
            print("Call is connected")
        }
        if call.isOutgoing {
            print("This is an outgoing call")
        } else if call.hasEnded == false && call.hasConnected == false {
            print("This is an incoming call")
        }
    }
}
```