# How to check which one button click?

Tags: ios, swift

How to check which button on click ?

can i get any notification start call is connected

```
 guard let number = URL(string: "tel://61234567890") else {

        print("exit")

        return }

    UIApplication.shared.open(number) { success in
        if success {
            print("successfuly opened")
        }
    }
```

[image: check my output]

Comment: How can i get user is click on call button ? please describe in detail

Comment: Start Observing calls via 'CallKit', if any delegate method regarding call get called, it means call button clicked

Comment: Since this dialog is presented by iOS, not your app, you cannot attach any event handler to it.

Comment: 'https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxproviderdelegate' you can refer this, you will get callback, when events related to call get appeared. So you can make `CXProvider` object and keep delegate for the same.

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54098708/2395636) to listen call events.

Comment: Kamran and MehulThakkar Thanks both of you.

Comment: Can i get number using CXProvider ?